# How to initiate a swiper js slider with reference to slick js

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js, swiper.js

a slick slider was started like below.

```
 var WidgetLAECarouselHandler = function ($scope, $) {

        var carousel_elem = $scope.find('.lae-carousel, .lae-posts-carousel, .lae-gallery-carousel, .lae-services-carousel').eq(0);

        if (carousel_elem.length > 0) {

            var settings = carousel_elem.data('settings');

            carousel_elem.slick({
                arrows: arrows,
                dots: dots,
                infinite: true,
```

but i am unable to initiate a swiper slider like above

```
carousel_elem.Swiper(
       '.cggowl-container', {
```

is there any method to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Swiper is initialized differently than Slick slider.
It also has different names for the properties in it's settings object.

Check out the Initialization section in [Swiper's API documentation](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#initialize).

From the documentation:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 100
});
```

You initialize Swiper by creating a new Swiper object and assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer so that it quotes the respective part from the source you cited.